# Eloquent DataTables casts all attributes to string

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, yajra-datatable

Eloquent DataTables casts all attributes to a string, even int ids.

PHP 7.2

Laravel Version 5.5

Yajra laravel-datatables Version 8.4

Mysql 8

Code snippet of problem

```
return \DataTables::eloquent(Users::where('isActive',1))
        ->make(true);
```

Comment: Maybe worth having a look at the issue on Github - https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is work for me

```
 return \DataTables::eloquent(Users::where('isActive',1))
        ->rawColumns(['id'])
        ->make(true);
```

added  ->rawColumns(['id'])  before ->make(true);